# adding text to meeting requests

Tags: vsto, exchangewebservices, office-addins

I'm new to office development.

For a project i'm on we would require to add a piece of text to any outgoing meeting request to an external party.  So if the 'plugin' is installed for company X (sent by john@companyx.com) and one of the invitees to the meeting is an external user (jane@othercompany.com) we would like to include a piece of text at the bottom of the meeting request.

as far as I can tell there's a few paths into this

- office javascript based add in
- VSTO add in
- exchange server add in (potentially?)

If at all possible, we'd want something that works on all platforms (which  leads me to think javascript api / EWS are the main contenders) and is fully automatic - ie no buttons to click for end users.

I'd appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction on this

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

What you want does not require any development of any app or add-in. You can achieve this by using transport rule, unless you want to create dynamic text based on email itself.

see the official guide by Microsoft.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600437(v=exchg.160).aspx

Comment: sorry - i'm being too literal when saying 'adding text'.  really what i mean is call a web service - get an id back, include the id in the text. eg www.gotohere.com/1234566

Comment: You have 2 options:
1: Create custom transport agent which will call web service or any other task native rule/agent can not do. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204097%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
2. You can block external meeting invite and give them simple app that can create meeting request for them. You can use Mail apps with Exchange 2013+.